# How to create an interface out of a class easily?

Tags: c#, class, interface, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a class which has 10 methods.
What i want is to create an interface of that class, i.e the interface will contain only the signature of those 10 methods.

Can it be done easily in .NET using Visual studio?

I am asking this question because I am changing the architecture of my project and for every class present in my project i need an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly can. You can use the [Extract Interface refactoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx) to do it for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using VS 2010 you can do this by just going to the Refractor Menu and click Extract Interface, you can also use the key board short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Pretty easy. think about it!

if seriously, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - will extract an interface of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for ReSharper's [Extract Interface](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Extract_Interface.html) refactoring feature.

Comment: This is an especially good answer if you use VS2008, which does not have it built in. however, you might also mention that there are free plugins that support this kind of refactoring, such as the free version of Refactor! Pro.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to go:

- Way 1: Using Visual Studio: Right Click on your Class body and the choose `Refactor>Extract Interface`, then choose `Members` and provide `Interface name` or keep default name if you want leading `I` in your class name.
- Way 2: After opening your `class`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>(case insensitive) and then do rest job according to `Way 1`